Why doesn't `FindInstance` work in finding Heronian triangle?
I was trying to find a triangle whose side lengths are all positive integers and area is rational number (similar to Heronian triangle)  with FindInstance, but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.
Clear["Global`*"];
p = (a + b + c)/2;
FindInstance[ Sqrt[p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)] == x/y, {a, b, c, x, y}, PositiveIntegers, 2]
(* FindInstance: The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist. *)

FindInstance[ 16*p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)*y^2 == 16*x^2 // FullSimplify, {a, b, c, x, y}, PositiveIntegers, 2]
(* It doesn't work, too. *)

{a, b, c, x, y} = {9, 10, 17, 36, 1};
Sqrt[p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)] == x/y


By the way, what is the point of using x/y when your goal is to find Heronian triangle, i.e. triangle with integer sides and area. It only slows down the searching and nothing more is found compared with y=1.

I see you edited the question so I updated my answer.

If you want a real challenge try to find the triangles that are described in the last paragraph of https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeronianTriangle.html.

Answer to the edited version of the question (finding triangle with integer sides but non-integer rational area):
Inside of the Sqrt must be a square number.
p = (a + b + c)/2;
Sqrt[p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)] // Factor


1/4 Sqrt[-a^4 + 2 a^2 b^2 - b^4 + 2 a^2 c^2 + 2 b^2 c^2 - c^4]

Here we test all possible combinations of sides of the form 16*k+0, 16*k+1, ..., 16*k+15.
Factor[-a^4 + 2 a^2 b^2 - b^4 + 2 a^2 c^2 + 2 b^2 c^2 - c^4 /. 
       a -> 16 a + #[[1]] /. b -> 16 b + #[[2]] /. 
     c -> 16 c + #[[3]]] & /@ (Union[
    Sort /@ Tuples[Range[0, 15], {3}]]);
PolynomialMod[%, 16] // Union


{0, 3, 7, 15}

We see that they are equal to {0, 3, 7, 15} modulo 16.
But square modulo 16 is {0, 1, 4, 9} as can be seen by:
PolynomialMod[(16 a + #)^2, 16] & /@ Range[0, 15] // Union


{0, 1, 4, 9}

The two outputs can coincide only in cases Intersection[{0, 3, 7, 15}, {0, 1, 4, 9}] == {0} which is the case of Heronian triangle because then 1/4 before Sqrt is cancelled out with output of Sqrt.
Therefore a triangle with integer sides and non-integer rational area can not exist.
I hope I did not make any mistakes and also hope I saved time for OP trying to search for a non-existent triangle.
Answer to the original question (finding Heronian triangle):
Specify upper bound for variables.
p = (a + b + c)/2;
FindInstance[
  Sqrt[p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)] == x && 0 < a <= b <= c <= 16, {a, 
   b, c, x}, PositiveIntegers, 10] // Column


{
 {{a -> 3, b -> 4, c -> 5, x -> 6}},
 {{a -> 9, b -> 12, c -> 15, x -> 54}},
 {{a -> 10, b -> 13, c -> 13, x -> 60}},
 {{a -> 6, b -> 8, c -> 10, x -> 24}},
 {{a -> 13, b -> 14, c -> 15, x -> 84}},
 {{a -> 10, b -> 10, c -> 16, x -> 48}},
 {{a -> 10, b -> 10, c -> 12, x -> 48}},
 {{a -> 5, b -> 12, c -> 13, x -> 30}},
 {{a -> 5, b -> 5, c -> 8, x -> 12}},
 {{a -> 5, b -> 5, c -> 6, x -> 12}}
}


@azerbajdzan the appropriate and relevant answer to OP +1

@ubpdqn Your is also good (+1). People are often lazy to do some simple brute force these days and want everything to be done automatically.

Here's a brute force way to get some:
sssq[{a_, b_, c_}] := 
  Quiet@SSSTriangle[a, b, c] /. {SSSTriangle[x___] :> False, 
    Triangle[x__] :> True};
cand = Select[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {1000, 3}], 
   sssq @@ # == True &];
{{##}, Graphics[SSSTriangle[##]], Area[SSSTriangle[##]]} & @@@ 
  DeleteDuplicatesBy[
   Select[IntegerQ[Area[SSSTriangle[Sequence @@ ##]]] &][cand], 
   Sort] // Grid



For larger parameter ranges  a,b,c>>25 FindInstances evaluates very slow. Here a primitive brute force does the job much  faster
nmax = 30;
p = (a + b + c)/2;
sol = DeleteCases[
   Table[If[
      Element[x = Sqrt[p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)], 
       PositiveRationals] , {a, b, c, x}, Nothing ], {a, 1, nmax}, {b,
       a, nmax}, {c, b, nmax}] // Flatten[#, 1] &  , {}] ; (*.1s*)

    (*{{{3, 4, 5, 6}}, {{3, 25, 26, 36}}, {{4, 13, 15, 24}}, {{5, 5, 6, 
   12}, {5, 5, 8, 12}}, {{5, 12, 13, 30}}, {{5, 29, 30, 72}}, {{6, 8, 
   10, 24}}, {{6, 25, 29, 60}}, {{7, 15, 20, 42}}, {{7, 24, 25, 
   84}}, {{8, 15, 17, 60}}, {{8, 26, 30, 96}}, {{9, 10, 17, 36}}, {{9,
    12, 15, 54}}, {{10, 10, 12, 48}, {10, 10, 16, 48}}, {{10, 13, 13, 
   60}}, {{10, 17, 21, 84}}, {{10, 24, 26, 120}}, {{11, 13, 20, 
   66}}, {{11, 25, 30, 132}}, {{12, 16, 20, 96}}, {{12, 17, 25, 
   90}}, {{13, 13, 24, 60}}, {{13, 14, 15, 84}}, {{13, 20, 21, 
   126}}, {{14, 25, 25, 168}}, {{15, 15, 18, 108}, {15, 15, 24, 
   108}}, {{15, 20, 25, 150}}, {{16, 17, 17, 120}}, {{17, 17, 30, 
   120}}, {{17, 25, 26, 204}, {17, 25, 28, 210}}, {{18, 24, 30, 
   216}}, {{20, 20, 24, 192}}, {{20, 21, 29, 210}}, {{20, 26, 26, 
   240}}, {{25, 25, 30, 300}}, {{26, 28, 30, 336}}}*)

addendum
With additional constraints for inner and outer radius of the triangle the solution {a,b,c,x,ri,ra}  is
nmax = 30;
p = (a + b + c)/2;
sol = DeleteCases[Table[x = Sqrt[p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)];
    If[x > 0 && Element[x, PositiveRationals] && 
      Element[{x/ p  , (a b c)/(4 x)}, PositiveIntegers], {a, b, c, x,
       x/p, (a b c)/(4 x)}, Nothing], {a, 1, nmax}, {b, a, nmax}, {c, 
     b, nmax}] // Flatten[#, 1] &, {}]
(*{{{6, 8, 10, 24, 2, 5}}, 
{{10, 24, 26, 120, 4, 13}}, 
{{12, 16, 20, 96,4, 10}}, 
{{18, 24, 30, 216, 6, 15}}}*)


It doesn't evaluate because of the system option. Please see my answer and how one can force FindInstance to work even for larger ranges.

@Domen Thanks for your hint.  I tried to point out, that FindInstance here is very slow. Case m=30 needs 93s to evaluate one solution, whereas my Table-approach evaluates all cases in 0.1s

Can you add two condintions are radius of the circumcircle of the triangle and radius of the inscribed circle of the triangle are integers?

I tried
nmax = 30; p = (a + b + c)/2; s = Sqrt[p *(p - a)* (p - b) *(p - c)]; r = s/p; R = (a *b *c)/(4*s); sol = DeleteCases[   Table[If[(a - b) (b - c) (c - a) != 0 && Element[r, Integers] &&        Element[R, Integers] &&        Element[x = Sqrt[p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)],         PositiveRationals], {a, b, c, x}, Nothing], {a, 1, nmax}, {b,       a, nmax}, {c, b, nmax}] // Flatten[#, 1] &, {}]

@minhthien_2016 I added the additional constraints in my answer. Where does condition (a - b) (b - c) (c - a) != 0 in your comment comes from?

@UlrichNeumann I am sorry. I add it by myself. I realized it wasn't necessary

As usual, FindInstance is not a magical function that can solve any problem you give it. It has to be able to transform the problem into a form which can be "solved" by the algorithms it has implemented. Here, it looks like we are out of luck.
However, as a last resort for integer equations, FindInstance can also do a naive, brute-force approach. But this is only performed when you bound the domain, for example:
p = (a + b + c)/2;
m = 10;
FindInstance[Sqrt[p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)] == x/y && a <= m && b <= m && 
  c <= m && x <= m && y <= m && a <= b <= c, {a, b, c, x, y}, PositiveIntegers]
(* {{a -> 3, b -> 4, c -> 5, x -> 6, y -> 1}} *)

If you set the value of m to a very large number, you will also have to change some options, as explained in my other answer.
m = 30;
SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> {"ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints" -> {1000, m^5}}];
FindInstance[Sqrt[p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)] == x/y && a <= m && b <= m && 
  c <= m && x <= m && y <= m && a <= b <= c, {a, b, c, x, y}, PositiveIntegers]
(* {{a -> 3, b -> 4, c -> 5, x -> 6, y -> 1}} *)


I'd like to use Z3 (in Pthon API. SMT-LIB 2 Standard is hard for me).
It really does work.
#!pip install z3-solver
from z3 import *

# Declare variables a, b, c, x, y as integers
a = Int('a')
b = Int('b')
c = Int('c')
x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')

# The semi-perimeter p
p = (a + b + c) / 2

# Define the expression using Heron's formula
area_square = p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c)

# Constraints to ensure all variables are positive integers
constraints = [
    a > 10,
    b > 10,
    c > 10,
    x > 0,
    y == 1,
    y * y * area_square == (x * x),
    2 * p == (a + b + c),
    a + b > c,
    b + c > a,
    c + a > b
]

# Initialize the solver and add constraints
solver = Solver()
solver.add(constraints)

# Check if the constraints are satisfiable
if solver.check() == sat:
    # Get the solution as a model
    model = solver.model()
    print("Solution:")
    print(f"a: {model[a]}")
    print(f"b: {model[b]}")
    print(f"c: {model[c]}")
    print(f"x: {model[x]}")
    print(f"y: {model[y]}")
else:
    print("No solution found.")

Solution:
a: 11
b: 20
c: 13
x: 66
y: 1


How is a python code an answer on a site about Wolfram Mathematica?

If you want a real challenge try to find the triangles that are described in the last paragraph of https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeronianTriangle.html.
